How to get the algebraic expression of the prism operator in any dimension?
I am reading Hatcher's Algebraic Topology and am curious about how to design the algebraic expression of the prism operator even if I know the intuition is to create a cylinder such that the boundary contains top face and bottom face. Furthermore, it implies that the homology is homotopy invariant. I looked up many materials and found no satisfying answers. Despite stack_ans telling me there is a relation with general simplicial sets, I don't know what happens and am convinced that the latter is only an analog of prism operator expression.
So my question is still how to guess the expression of the prism operator? Only through computation of dim $1, 2$ and induction? I hope there is a beautiful method other than Hatcher's proof and  Tom Deick's induction method.
Look forward to your answers.

The prism operator is obtained from the canonical triangulation of $\Delta^n\times\Delta^1$. You have linked a very detailed answer explaining exactly that already. So, what is it exactly that you are missing? Saying "I don't know what happens" is not precise enough to give you an answer that would not just be a retread of the answer that was already linked.

T'he related answer seems to only tell me the nondegenerate simplices in the answer gives the triangulation. But I don't know how to explain why it gives the triangulation of cylinder into n-simplices.

If you're looking for a proof, it is in the references that the answer lists.
